# Story where there's a man about to murder somebody and at the end it turns out to be you

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I've been trying forever to remember the title of this story. I read it when I was in high school for one of my classes, so I don't remember much.
The main character was a man and I think it was a first person narration.
Can't recall the pieces in between, but he's basically looking for somebody in this place.
He takes you through his quest explaining his thought process.
At the end he finds the unknown person he was looking for, and lurks quietly from behind while pulling a knife. As he gets closer, the author makes a clever trick (something about him seeing that person reading a story) to let you know the one that he's about to murder is actually you.
It game me chills and I had to chech that there wasn't anybody behind me. It'd be great if someone can help me out!

Comment: I feel like this entire question (and title) needs a spoiler tag :-)

Comment: Sorry about that, kind of the only thing I remember :P

Comment: Is it a science fiction or fantasy story? Ordinary crime stories are not on topic here.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's really not science fiction or fantasy.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The story you're looking for is "[Don't Look Behind You](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?64756)" by Fredric Brown and is almost certainly not science fiction/fantasy. While Justin sees Harley after Harley's death, it's heavily implied to be a hallucination from nearly being killed before being dumped in the swamp.

Here are the opening lines:

> Just sit back and relax, now. Try to enjoy this; it’s going to be the last story you ever read, or nearly the last. After you finish it you can sit there and stall awhile, you can find excuses to hang around your house, or your room, or your office, wherever you’re reading this; but sooner or later you’re going to have to get up and go out. That’s where I’m waiting for you: outside. Or maybe closer than that. Maybe in this room.

Comment: I know it wasn't really topic related but totally worth the shot. Thanks so much man!

Comment: Yeah. It's kind of a shame we don't have another Stack Exchange to send questions like this to. TVTropes's YKTS at http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/query.php?type=ykts is a good start and there's always Stump the Bookseller if you're really stuck.