# Looking for a short story in which the narrator describes how he has placed the pages of the story specifically for "you"

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, anthology-book

The story was in a hardcover short story collection. I read it in the early 80s, and the book seemed older to me at the time. The narrator eventually goes on to describe how they are watching you.

Comment: An interesting start, can you provide any more details about how much older it seemed at the time? Also at the moment it doesn't have any particular details about this being a science-fiction or fantasy anthology? Do you remember any stories that had any themes that would make it on-topic for this site? Any other details that might help someone identify this particular story?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the work identified is not science-fiction or fantasy

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[*Don't Look Behind You*](https://gravetapping.blogspot.com/2015/03/dont-look-behind-you-by-fredric-brown.html) by Fredric Brown, originally published in Ellery Queen's Magazine in May 1947 and in many places [thereafter](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?64756)

> “Don’t Look Behind You” is a cleverly plotted story that takes you in
> one direction only to quickly and smoothly swerve into another, and
> then another. It opens with a raw slash of narrative:
>
> “Just sit back and relax, now. Try to enjoy this; it’s going to be the
> last story you ever read, or nearly the last. After you finish it you
> can sit there and stall awhile, you can find excuses to hang around
> your house, or your room, or your office, wherever you’re reading
> this; but sooner or later you’re going to have to get up and go out.
> That’s where I’m waiting for you: outside. Or maybe closer than that.
> Maybe in this room.”
>
> It is told in first person with a twist—the narrator isn’t necessarily
> who you think it is and the story doesn’t necessarily lead you where
> you think it is will. The prose is spot on; re-read the passage above
> and if you don’t want to read more you’re crazy. But the best part of
> the story is its plot and the affect it has on the reader. The
> narrator speaks directly to the reader—not as an audience member, but
> as a principle character—and it has a chilling effect that made me
> shudder with bliss in the closing paragraphs.

Comment: If so, we've [had it before](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/100861/story-where-theres-a-man-about-to-murder-somebody-and-at-the-end-it-turns-out-t/100868#100868), and the consensus has been that it's not SF&F, with the closest to fantasy being the narrator imagining his dead friend following him through the swamp, but it's clear that he's actually hallucinating.

Comment: Yeah, even ISFDB lists it as "non-genre"